# How to keep the audio size, reduced, while recording in android?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, reduce, emmet

My requirement is to keep the size of audio as small as i can. Also, after getting the recorded stream, i can accomplish this task by zencoder type APIs but I am interested to do this thing while recording.

Thanks
Talha

Comment: Did you find any way for reducing the recorded audio file (.amr) size ?

Answer (score 0):

MediaRecorder supports AMR encoding which is very efficient. The size of the resulting file will grow at 1600 bytes/second.